# Proof by induction long question

Tags: induction

I've been trying to figure this question out for a while:

An algorithm takes one operation to sort an array with one item in it. When the number of items in the array increases from n to n+1, at most an additional 2n+1 operations are required. Use proof by induction to show that the number of operations required to sort the array with n>0 items in it requires at most n<sup>2</sup> operations.

I understand proof by induction, and have done several examples pf shorter-style questions however can't think how to extract the required information from this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inductively suppose we are done out to stage $k$.  So stage $k$ requires at most $k^2$ operations.  Now, how many operations might stage $k+1$ require?  How does that compare to $(k+1)^2$?

Comment: General note:  when confused, it's always a good idea to keep things explicit.  As usual, we are handed the case $n=1$ as an assumption,  So, then, what about $n=2$?  $n=3$?  Keep going until you see a general pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basis for induction: For n = 1, the result holds.

Induction hypothesis: Suppose $k^2$ operations are required to sort k terms.

Inductive step:For k+1 terms, maximum operations required are the maximum operations required for k terms+ maximum operations required for the next step

=$k^2+(2k+1)$

=$(k+1)^2$

Hence proved

Hope it is helpful